# Redirect::back() is not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

```
if(count($data) == 1)
{
return view('home');
}
else {
// echo"ta-da";
Redirect::back()->with('message','username or password not Match!'); 
}
```

Above Redirect::back() function is not working while login.
If I'm printing anything it is showing

Comment: `return Redirect::back()->with('message','username or password not Match!');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to redirect you have to use laravel builtin function

```
return redirect()->back()->with('msg_name', 'your message');
```

or you can use route() method instate of back() method

```
return redirect()->route('your.route.name')->with('msg_name', 'your message');
```

Comment: thanks saifur rahman, it's work. thanks for your supporting.

Answer (score 9):

You need to `return` the redirection

Answer (score 0):

Use **return** before redirect to redirect to the route